Tailwind CSS Plugins Error Loading with Parcel
I have the following Tailwind CSS config file.
// See the Tailwind default theme values here:
// https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/blob/master/stubs/defaultConfig.stub.js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],

  // All the default values will be compiled unless they are overridden below
  theme: {
    // Extend (add to) the default theme in the `extend` key
    extend: {
      colors: {
        // Create your own at: https://javisperez.github.io/tailwindcolorshades
        primary: colors.blue,
        secondary: colors.emerald,
        tertiary: colors.gray,
        danger: colors.red,
        gray: colors.neutral,
        'code-400': '#fefcf9',
        'code-600': '#3c455b',
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        serif: ['IBM Plex Serif', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.serif],
      },
    },
  },

  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/container-queries'),
    require('tailwindcss-debug-screens'),
  ],

  // Opt-in to TailwindCSS future changes
  future: {},
};

I am using Parcel to run the server and get the following error:
 Build failed.

@parcel/transformer-postcss: Cannot find module '@tailwindcss/typography'
Require stack:
- /Users/harshamv/Sites/tailwind-starter/tailwind.config.js

  Error: Cannot find module '@tailwindcss/typography'
  Require stack:
  - /Users/harshamv/Sites/tailwind-starter/tailwind.config.js
      at Function._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1224:15)
      at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/helpers:190:19)
      at _resolve (/Users/harshamv/Sites/tailwind-starter/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:251148)
      at jiti (/Users/harshamv/Sites/tailwind-starter/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:253746)
      at /Users/harshamv/Sites/tailwind-starter/tailwind.config.js:32:5
      at evalModule (/Users/harshamv/Sites/tailwind-starter/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:256443)
      at jiti (/Users/harshamv/Sites/tailwind-starter/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:254371)
      at /Users/harshamv/Sites/tailwind-starter/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/load-config.js:52:30
      at loadConfig (/Users/harshamv/Sites/tailwind-starter/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/load-config.js:54:6)
      at getTailwindConfig (/Users/harshamv/Sites/tailwind-starter/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/setupTrackingContext.js:71:116)

I tried install the plugins manually and try but still getting the same error.

Does the error still persist if you disable the auto install, clean the node_modules and manually install the plugins?
